# Why can't I register SessionFactory as a bean?

Tags: spring, hibernate, javabeans, sessionfactory

I want to register SessionFactory as a bean and autowire it with a DAO bean.
I seems not allowed to do in this way and I don't know why..

First, I tried like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MemoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberDao memberDao() {
        SessionFactory factory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
                                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                        .addAnnotatedClass(Member.class)
                                        .addAnnotatedClass(Memo.class)
                                        .buildSessionFactory();
        return new MemberDao(factory);
    }
}
```

and I got errors.
So, I tried another way:

```
@Configuration
public class MemoConfig {
    @Bean
    public MemberDao memberDao() {
        return new MemberDao(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        SessionFactory factory = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Member.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Memo.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and I got the same error messages.

Here are the error messages.

```
09-Apr-2019 14:04:48.700 심각 [http-nio-8181-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberDao' defined in com.myMemo.app.configuration.MemoConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.myMemo.app.member.MemberDao]: Factory method 'memberDao' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.myMemo.app.configuration.MemoConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
...


Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at com.myMemo.app.configuration.MemoConfig.sessionFactory(MemoConfig.java:24)
    at com.myMemo.app.configuration.MemoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41a7e678.CGLIB$sessionFactory$1(<generated>)
    at com.myMemo.app.configuration.MemoConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$41a7e678$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75fa1e22.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
```

Comment: I found that I should use LocalSessionFactoryBuilder but I want to know why what I tried doesn't work.

Comment: You would need to post the exact and complete stack trace for us to be able to help.

Comment: Do you have a database as defined in your configuration file or is your database server running or do you have the required jar files for database connectivity? It might be that you have at least one of these issues that is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Kenrig 
I think the configuration has no problem. Because it works well if I don't use spring bean. I created an independent class for test and tried to connect DB using SessionFactory and it worked well.

Comment: I think the solution for your problem is addressed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400446/hibernate-sessionfactory-annotation-based-configuration